# How to get data from commandline wappalyzer phantomjs?

Tags: phantomjs

I need to get data of url using wappalyzer phantomjs.When i am running phantomjs on commandline then it is working fine.but i need to get the json response on webpage.Can i get the response on webpage using php or some other way.I am not getting full example of it.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with php.

$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true driver.js http://example.com');
echo json_decode($output,true);

Note : Change this "/usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/" to directory where you installed the phantomjs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the command:

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true driver.js http://example.com'); echo json_decode($output,true);
```

**Note** : Change this "`/usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/`" to directory where you installed the `phantomjs`.